# What is the significance of CONFRIMATION page in DRUPAL?

Tags: drupal

This is one of the same page which gets displayed whenever we try deleting (it gets displayed on various other events as well) bunch of nodes from the CONTENT page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is about the Cross-Site Request Forgery `(CSRF or XSRF)`. Being a web developer I knew this term for sure but was unaware about its linking with 'Confirmation Page'.

**What is Cross-Site Request `Forgery(CSRF or XSRF)`?**

`CSRF` is an attack which enforces an end user (authenticated user) to perform some operation without his intend.

**Drupal scenario of CSRF attack**

Most of the Drupal site do have a feedback form implemented through Webform. As a default behaviour Webform sends the feedback form submissions to an email as well.

1. Attacker can trick this message by adding some link with href parameter as [http://www.examplesite.com/node/3/delete?destination=admin/content].
2. Now authenticated user might click on the link in the message without the knowledge of operational sensitivity of href [http://www.examplesite.com/node/3/delete?destination=admin/content].
3. By the time user realizes the attack - link is already clicked and it is too late to revert the action as the [node/4] is already deleted and [admin/content] page is displayed.

**Drupal's way of preventing `CSRF`**

1. Drupal associates a secret TOKEN value with every actions.
   ---We can find [form_token] as a hidden field in forms in Drupal.
2. Whenever any action (such as deleting the node/s) is sent to the browser, drupal site will also send the associated TOKEN value to the browser.
3. Importance of this TOKEN - this is known only to user and the site. Its very hard for attackers to trick suck TOKENS.
4. Whenever browser sends any request to the site - Drupal validates the TOKEN against action and then only required action will be performed.
5. If this `Action + Token` validation fails then action is declined.